# How can I create a graph from an equation with two unknowns with python?

Tags: python, plot

I want to create a probably plot with a equation and two unknowns but I didn't success...
Here is my script

```
from numpy import exp, sqrt, linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import meshgrid, cm, imshow, contour, clabel, colorbar, axis, title, show

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 5]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True


def f(x, y):
return (1 / sqrt(x)) * exp(-y / 50) * (1 - exp(-x / 1097) * (2 * exp(-y / (2 * 50)) - 1))


x = linspace(10, 1000, 990)
y = linspace(10, 50, 40)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
```

Thank you so much !!

I would like to have a x value between 10 and 1000 and y value between 10 and 50 for example. And obtain this kind of plot.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [This Link](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html) You can use matplotlibs 3d plotting api. Here's an example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
plt.xlim(10, 1000)
plt.ylim(10, 50)
# Some Different Types of Plots That You can Use:
ax.scatter3D(X, Y, Z, c=Z, cmap='Greens')
# ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color='black')
# ax.plot3D(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Z.flatten())
# ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 990, cmap='binary')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```